# Encrypted swap partition not available

Tags: 14.04, encryption, swap

How should I correctly set up my encrypted swap partition?  How can I ensure that the setup persists?

I'm running 14.04 using encrypted home folder.  I noticed that occasionally my machine would grind to a complete halt for a minute or so.  I finally realized that my machine showed that it did not have any swap space set up and my memory was filling up and nothing could be swapped when this happened.

`/dev/sda6` is the partition of interest in my case.

**How I Made Swap Work Yesterday**

I reformatted the swap partition to `linux-swap` format via `gparted` and put its UUID, obtained from `blkid /dev/sda6`, in the appropriate `/etc/crypttab` entry.  I then rebooted the system.  Swap file was available and working correctly.

**How Swap Stopped Working Again**

Uncertain.

---

Steps I've taken to diagnose this situation, things I modified, etc.:

- `free -m` shows 0MB total swap space available

  ```
  dmays@vipertooth:~$ free -m
               total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
  Mem:          5875       2238       3636        270         98       1007
  -/+ buffers/cache:       1133       4741
  Swap:            0          0          0
  ```
- `gparted` shows the swap partition as "Unknown"

[image: gparted screenshot -- /dev/sda6 is partition of interest]

- `blkid /dev/sda6` returns exit code 2.
- `swapon -s` shows only column headers

  ```
  dmays@vipertooth:~$ swapon -s
  Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
  ```
- `swapon -a` fails with exit code 255

  ```
  dmays@vipertooth:~$ sudo swapon -a
  [sudo] password for dmays: 
  swapon: /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: stat failed: No such file or directory
  ```
- modified `/etc/crypttab` from yesterday

  ```
  cryptswap1 UUID=4602a330-ead0-4198-be26-47a5b16666e1 /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
  ```
- examined `fstab` -- it appears my /home may not be encrypted???

  ```
  # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
  # / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
  UUID=b09ec379-a94d-4905-b4ac-2f5c62b5605d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
  # /home was on /dev/sda7 during installation
  UUID=d57bf732-77df-44fe-b547-d15a48dd1857 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
  # swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
  /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
  ```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swap not working on clean 14.04 install using encrypted home](http://askubuntu.com/questions/462775/swap-not-working-on-clean-14-04-install-using-encrypted-home)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This appears to be a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/1310058).

Credit to [redsandro's answer on a duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/a/541514/219726) for info about the bug and a quick fix for it.

I implemented the "Easy Fix" as stated in the above answer and [by user foenhn-2 in a comment to the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/1310058/comments/6).  Even though this fix is functional I may attempt to get the offset=X method to work in order to keep the swap partition's UUID intact.